# Почему не происходит сортировка вложенного списка, методом list[0].sort()? Python

Tags: python

Не пойму почему не сортируется вложенный список.

```
square1 = [[2, 3, 4, 1], [3, 4, 1, 2], [4, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
a = square1[0].sort()
print(a)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Выражение бессмысленное, т.к. `sort` не возвращает значение списка:

```
a = square1[0].sort()
print(a)
```

Чтобы убедиться в сортировке нужно вывести общий список или конкретно тот, что был подвергнут сортировке:

```
print(square1)
print(square1[0])
```

Но если в `a` нужен новый сортированный список, тогда используйте метод `sorted`:

```
a = sorted(square1[0])
print(a)
```

Answer (score 4):

Вы присваиваете переменной не ссылку на список, а результат метода сортировки. Метод сортировки возвращает `None`, т.е. ничего не возвращает.

Вы не должны присваивать результат метода переменной:

```py
square1 = [[2, 3, 4, 1], [3, 4, 1, 2], [4, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
square1[0].sort()
print(square1[0])
```

***stdout:***

```py
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```